# return array of indices of all values in an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have an array of arrays, and I want to get an array of the indexes of elements.
I start with this:

```
[
  [1,2,3],
  [-1],
  [-1],
  [4,5,6],
  [-1],
  [],
  []
]
```

And I want:

```
[1,2,4]
```

Some of the elements might be not be filled yet (they will get filled over time), but I want to specify which ones are **deliberately empty**. That's what the -1 signifies (I could as easily use **null**).

I'm sure **filter** is the right thing to use, but I don't want the element; I just want the index of the element.

I'm sure I can do it with a few loops and iterations, but that seems to be overkill.

Comment: array.map is your friend. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Thank you, although I've never understood map - it's so ... abstract and flexible - and don't know how I would implement it. I'll try to get my head around it.

Comment: `.map` must return something into the resulting array upon each iteration of the original array. If you want to exclude entries into the resulting array that don't match your criteria, `.map` won't do it.

Comment: sorry i was quick to respond in this case you would use array.reduce https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: the best approach for your scenario is to use `reduce`, as it's already answered.

Comment: under the hood, both `.map, filter or reduce` use iteration but for the sake of semantic meaning, they're introduced for easier naming. The biggest difference is they return a new array value, not override any thing to original array, and can be chain-able (like .map().filter().map() ). While you cannot do this with simple loops.

Comment: You can do this using map function too. I posted an answer using map.

Comment: *"I want to get an array of the indexes of elements"* I think this needs some clarity - I don't know why you'd want an end-result of `[1,2,4]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more manual that it could be, but very understandable.

```js
let input = [
  [1,2,3],
  [-1],
  [-1],
  [4,5,6],
  [-1],
  [],
  []
];

let output = [];

// Loop over original array
input.forEach(function(item, index){
    // If length of current item is 1 and that one item is the "deliberately 
    // empty" indicator, push its index into result array
    item.length === 1 && item[0] === -1 ? output.push(index) : null;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: There's also `item.length === 1 && item[0] === -1 && output.push(index);` which avoids the `null` and ternary, but maybe just writing an `if` is clearest. Variables can also be `const`.

Comment: Wow. I have been away from vanilla JS so long, I did not know it had a native forEach function. I will check that out. And it's not magic!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)'s third parameter to access each element's index, then use the callback to conditionally extend the result array if the current element matches your flag variable.

```js
const result = [
  [1,2,3],
  [-1],
  [-1],
  [4,5,6],
  [-1],
  [],
  []
].reduce((a, e, i) => e.length === 1 && e[0] === -1 ? a.concat(i) : a, []);

console.log(result);
```

Having said that, your original version as well as your suggestion of using `null` rather than the `[-1]` [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) seems less prone to error. Here is code which tests for `null` elements as distinct from empty arrays:

```js
const emptyIdxes = [
  [1,2,3],
  [],
  null,
  [7,8,9],
  null
].reduce((a, e, i) => e === null ? a.concat(i) : a, []);

console.log(emptyIdxes);
```

Comment: I'm not sure your second code snippet works properly given that some entries in the array may be empty - what happens if the input to your second code snippet is the same as in the first snippet?

Comment: I tried this and it works (with -1). The downside is that, for me, it's magic.

Comment: @Nick I don't quite follow. In the bottom snippet, I'm talking about using a different scheme than the `[-1]` as a flag--going back to using `[]` or `null` as the flag. So using the top input doesn't really make sense on the bottom input (it'd return `[5, 6]`).

Comment: @ggorlen there's no way to distinguish in your second approach between empty arrays (nothing written) and those which are deliberately empty (those with a null/-1 value)

Comment: Weird. It does not work with null or with "" - they return an empty array. It only works with -1. I double checked the syntax on testing for 'null'. Unfortunately, -1 is treated as a valid value for an element in the array, so it shoes up in the totals and display. Which means I need subsequent test to weed out -1.

Comment: Hmm--I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish here or what the specific issue you're describing is--do you want to use nulls as the flag variable now or are you trying to reject -1 anywhere in the array? That would require changes to the logic. I'm only detecting indexes of literally `[-1]` at present. This whole approach of using magic values is a pretty brittle way of doing things. See [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and can you offer a bit more context or update your post to show failing input with actual/expected?

Comment: In my post, above, (about 20 minutes before yours) that starts with "Elaborating on my comment above...", I've provided my code using reduce() and its outputs. Looks like Marcus' forEach method - to assemble a new array from scratch - works.

Comment: I'm still totally confused about what you're asking. Marcus' version using forEach is functionally identical to this one. The only difference is whether the accumulator array is passed into the function or not. In both cases the relevant logic is `e.length === 1 && e[0] === -1` which is identical to `item.length === 1 && item[0] === -1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented Scott Marcus' suggestion of using a forEach loop to manually generate a new array.

While other solutions using map(), reduce() or filter() may be faster or require less processing cycles, I prefer this solution for being much more readable and much more debuggable. This is important, since hopefully this code will outlive my involvement in it, and the next coder should be able to decipher it easily.

Below is an example input. It is an (outer) array of the first ten weeks of a darts game, each element is its own (inner) array, containing the scores of the eight teams. Only the first two weeks have been scored so far.

Weeks 7 and 8 are holidays, and so should be greyed out in the HTML table. Holidays can be marked at the beginning of the season, regardless of how many weeks have been played.

```
var arrScore = [
  [2,1,1,2,2,1,2,1],
  [2,2,2,0,1,1,3,1],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [null],/* holiday */
  [null],/* holiday */
  [],
  [] /* etc. */
];
```

Because I process the holidays in a separate function from the scores, I want a nice clean (new) array so I can run through the weeks and just mark up holidays, independent of processing the scoring. And empty weeks that are holidays (and thus, will never have scores) must be distinguishable from weeks that merely don't have scores *yet*.

The (new) array I want, based on above example, would be [6,7], which is the (zero-based) index of the [null] elements.

```
arrScore.forEach(function(item, index){
    item.length === 1 && item[0] === null ? holidays.push(index) : null;
});

console.log(holidays);

=

[6,7]
```

The **forEach()** merely iterates over the (outer) array, and if it finds a element that

- is an (inner) array of length one, and
- has the first element of that (inner) array as null,

it simply pushes the index of that element (of the outer array) into a new holidays array.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function too

```js
var arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [-1],
    [-1],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [-1],
    [],
    []];

    
var arr2 = [];
const map1 = arr.map(x => x == -1 ? arr2.push(arr.indexOf(x)) : "");

console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: Turns out -1 is interpreted as a valid array element, and gets processed as a valid value, so I can't use it after all. I tried your technique with null and 'null', but they output an empty array.

Comment: Why would you use `map` instead of `forEach` when you don't care about the result of the map?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery because in the question he is clearly saying that he doesn't want to loop ."I'm sure I can do it with a few loops and iterations, but that seems to be overkill." And I didn't use filter function because there was an answer using filter already.

Comment: @SachinthaNayanajith If `forEach` is a loop then so is `map`. They're literally exactly the same except that `map` also returns a value.